# Why are random generated numbers UInt-32 by default in Swift?

Tags: swift, random, uint32

I stumbled upon the fact that when a random number is generated in Swift, it is of type `UInt32` by default instead of type `Int`

What's the reason?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you are referring to `arc4random`. This function returns `UInt32` because [the underlying C function](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random.3.html) (also called `arc4random`) returns `uint32_t`, which is the C equivalent of Swift's `UInt32`.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume it makes it faster. If you want Int random numbers take a look at GKRandomSource in the game kit, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gameplaykit/gkrandomsource